# Перевести XML в XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста перевести созданный XML файл в XSL.

```css
food{
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    background: #EA80FC;
    flex-direction: column; 
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px 15px 15px 15px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 250px;
}

name {
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: 'Arial', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4A148C;
 margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
}

description{
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 display: flex;
}

price{
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="style1.css"?>

<!DOCTYPE breakfast_menu [
  <!ELEMENT breakfast_menu (food, name*)>
  <!ELEMENT food (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT food (name, description, price)>
  <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
]>


<breakfast_menu>
<food>
<name>Бельгийские Вафли</name>
<price>$5.95</price>
<description>две известных Бельгийских Вафли с обилием настоящего кленового сиропа</description>
</food>
<food>
<name>Бельгийские Вафли с Земляникой</name>
<price>$7.95</price>
<description>легкие Бельгийские вафли с земляникой, покрытые взбитыми сливками</description>
</food>
<food>
<name>Бельгийские Вафли с Ягодами</name>
<price>$8.95</price>
<description>легкие Бельгийские вафли с различными свежими ягодами, покрытые взбитыми сливками</description>
</food>
<food>
<name>Французский Тост</name>
<price>$4.50</price>
<description>толстые куски, сделанные из кусочков домашнего хлеба из опары</description>
</food>
<food>
<name>Домашний Завтрак</name>
<price>$6.95</price>
<description>пара яиц, бекон или колбаса, тост, и наши всегда популярные картофельные оладьи</description>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

Comment: [XSL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL) - это то, с помощью чего делают преобразование. А не во что.

Comment: Хорошо, а как тогда с ним преобразовать XML документ?

Comment: @Matc Преобразовать во что?

Comment: Разработать XSL для преобразования созданных XML-документов

Comment: Так, уже лучше. Исходный xml есть. Теперь нужен вид xml, в который будем преобразовывать. И при чём здесь css?